# Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules guava-16.0.1.jar and listenablefuture-1.0.jar

Tags: android, guava, androidx

Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules guava-16.0.1.jar (com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1) and listenablefuture-1.0.jar (com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0)

Answer (score 2):

Change dependency

```
implementation "com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava"
```

Comment: after adding this line in build.gradle my issue waf resolve. implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'

Comment: @Hardik if you find my answer correct then mark it as Correct, it will be helpful for other as well